# Mostrar texto HTML em ASP TextBox?

Tags: html, asp.net, formatação, textbox

Estou a tentar mostrar um texto formatado em `HTML` em uma `asp text box` e não estou a conseguir.

Por exemplo este texto formatado: `<font size="6">teste</font>`, gostaria que quando exibisse esse texto na `text box` aparecesse já formatado, actualmente aparece com `tags`, tal como está acima.

Há alguma maneira através do `code behind` sem utilizar `eval` ou `bind`?

Comment: Você quer que seu textbox (ex.: `<input type="text" />`) esteja formatado (CSS)?

Comment: Estou a utilizar `<asp:TextBox>`, quero que o conteúdo esteja automaticamente formatado. Utilizo `AjaxTooKit` para o `HTMLEditorExtender`.

Comment: Desculpe, acho que não poderei ajudar. Só consigo alterar o CSS geral.

Comment: A única coisa que queria era que a `asp text box` mostrasse o texto formatado e não as `tags`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o que você quer é o `<asp:Literal>`, ele serve justamente para exibir algum texto estático, seja `HTML` ou não.

Exemplo:

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Literal id="meuLiteral" runat=server />
</form>
```

E no seu **CodeBehind**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    meuLiteral.Text = "<font size="6">teste</font>";
    meuLiteral.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough; /* sem modificações */        
}
```

---

#### TextBox com CSS

Agora se você quer um `<asp:textBox>` mesmo, é só criar uma *seletor CSS*:

```
.textbox
{ 
   font-size: 12px;
}
```

E no seu componente:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

---

#### TextBox [`FontSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontunit(v=vs.110).aspx) Dinâmico

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    meuTextBox.Font.Size = FontUnit.Large;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, mas há alguma forma de colocar a informação do género como uma `textbox`?

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Se você quer usar um `TextBox` pro usuário digitar e alterar o `font size` é só criar uma classe CSS

Comment: O utilizador por defeito usa o `HtmlEditorExtender` do `AjaxToolKit`, daí as formatações nunca serem pré-definidas.

Comment: @ChiragGeiantilal Atualizei minha resposta, vê se alguma te atende.